# Search engine opimization dos and don'ts for AJAX

Tags: ajax, seo, search-engine

I've created an AJAX enabled web application. In my application all contents [that I want to be appear in search pages] are loaded using AJAX. However I observed that despite of valid sitemap submitted to google, my page raking is very very poor.

What all I need to do and what to avoid in order to improve page ranking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to make it enabled for bookmark and history.  There are many ways.  One of them is jQuery's history plugin:  https://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin

you probably want to create a page for search engines to crawl your website with those links  `http://www.mysite.com/foobar.php#!fetch_content=xyz`.  The `#!` is a way recognized by Google to crawl and index its content.

reference: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

Answer (score 1):

Don'ts would be interesting. But here's a do, for all of JS as well.
Make sure that all links degrade gracefully, this can be easily achieved by giving the links real URLs that lead to the same content that is to be loaded in the event that JS is not enabled. This makes crawling your website possible.

You would also have to disable default for all the affected links.